# Should rand be used for an IV?

Tags: c, random, aes, cbc-mode, initialization-vector

CBC mode for AES specifies that to make each message unique, an IV should be used. The IV should be random and only used once, otherwise it may allow people to decrypt other cipher texts which used the same key.

Is the `rand()` function in C suitable for generating this IV? Does the fact that it is normally seeded with the current time make it vulnerable to some sort of attack?

Comment: The IV needs to be unpredictable for CBC mode. If `rand` really only uses the current time as a seed, then this might not be secure (depending on the overall protocol).

Comment: No; `rand()` is not cryptographically random.  It is extremely unlikely to be useful if you want any security.  The chances are it only yields 31 bits of pseudo-randomness, and that simply isn't enough to be useful for security.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i thought it only had to be random enough to stop replay attacks?

Comment: Use something more decent like libsodium, or hardware random generator. You can also use online generators

Comment: Yes, but that means cryptographically random enough — and `rand()` is not anywhere near random enough.  Reading from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` might be OK; it would certainly be better than `rand()`.  Remember, unless you call `srand()`, using `rand()` will generate the same 'random' number sequence each time it is used.  Calling `srand()` requires a value to kick things off.  But the internals of `rand()` are known to your attackers; they can predict what's happening.

Comment: And don't trust online generators (if i interpreted this advice correctly as: use some online-service to ask for randomness).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer is **NO**.  Don't use a non cryptographically-secure random generator for initialization vectors.  The initialization vectors are sent unencrypted, so one could think they can be generated by one of these functions.  But this should lead to weakness, and I'll explain:  If you use a poor (and `rand()` is such a weak random routine) you'll narrow the space of possible IVs you are generating.  An example will suffice:

Let's suppose you are using a 8 bytes IV in some encrypted message.  But the random function you use has a 8 bit seed, there are only 256 possible byte sequences to be generated from such a poor random function, so probably there will be only a maximum of 256 possible IVs generated (even if they show pure randomness, or a wide spread hash values over the whole space)  An attacker knowing this, can reproduce the whole 256 space of possible IV making them completely useless.

Comment: The IV is sent in the clear, so the attacker doesn't need to reproduce it.  And while an 8-bit seed makes for only 256 different streams, having an unknown position within those streams makes for more possible 8 byte subsequences (though if the assertion is it's being reseeded every call then, yeah, it'd be only 256).

Comment: @bartonjs, The IV is sent in the clear, you are right, but it has a size and must be made of equally probable bits with maximum entropy.  Almost all these requirements are met by a small seed good entropy random generator, but the last.  Maximum entrophy cannot be achieved if the seed has only 8 bits, you'll have maximum 256 IVs, and this is no entrophy at all.  If the seed is reseeded, then what entrophy generation are you using? are you reseeding it from another random generator?  Do you see my approach?